# Why the elements of the linked list is not showing after changing the return type of the functions create_ll and display from struct node* to void?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have written a linked list program and want to perform the operation of creating the linked list and displaying the elements of the list. As per the before code the `create_ll` and `display` functions both have return type as `struct node *`. I tried changing the return type to `void`, but the `display` function is not displaying the elements. I guess it has something to do with the return of start pointer. What's wrong??

BEFORE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *create_ll(struct node *);     //create_ll function
struct node *display(struct node *);      //display function
int main()
{
    start = create_ll(start);
    start = display(start);
    return 0;
}
struct node *create_ll(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *new_node,*ptr;
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter -1 to end"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the data: "<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    while(num!=-1)
    {
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->data = num;
        if(start == NULL)
        {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            start = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr=start;
            while(ptr->next != NULL)
            ptr=ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }
        cout<<"Enter the data"<<endl;
        cin>>num;
    }
    return start;
}
struct node *display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = start;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

AFTER:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *start = NULL;
void create_ll(struct node *);   //change create_ll function
void display(struct node *);     //changed display function
int main()
{
    create_ll(start);            //changed
    display(start);              //changed
    return 0;
}
void create_ll(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *new_node,*ptr;
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter -1 to end"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the data: "<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    while(num!=-1)
    {
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->data = num;
        if(start == NULL)
        {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            start = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr=start;
            while(ptr->next != NULL)
            ptr=ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }
        cout<<"Enter the data"<<endl;
        cin>>num;
    }                                              //return start; (removed)
}
void display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = start;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first version you use the return value to set the variable in `main()`.  In the second, you change the local copy within `create_ll()`, but leave the version in the caller unchanged.  If you want the variable in `main()` changed as well, as before, you'll have to add another level of indirection (pass pointer to pointer instead of just pointer to `create_ll()` and modify the body accordingly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

```
void create_ll(struct node *start);
```

deals with a copy of the original head node start. So changing the copy does not influence on the value of the original head node.

In the first program you are updating the value of the original head node by the returned value of the changed copy of the node.

```
start = create_ll(start);
```

So if you want that the function deal with the original head node (not with its value copy) you have to pass the head node by reference in the C++ meaning ir in C meaning. For example
C++

```
void create_ll(struct node * &start);
```

C

```
void create_ll(struct node **start);
```

As for the function display then in the first program it has undefined behavior because it returns nothing.:)

```
start = display(start);
//…

struct node *display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = start;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

If to define a return value of the function then there is a sense to declare the return type as `std::ostream &`

For example

```
std::ostream & display( node * start, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( node *current = start; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}
```

In this case it can for example be called like

```
display( start, std::cout << "List: " ) << '\n';
```

Pay attention to that in C++ you should use the operator new instead of the direct call of the function malloc as you are doing

```
new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Change this statement to

```
new_node = new node;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you pass a pointer to `start` as a copy to your create function and the global one that you have `struct node *start = NULL;` is not changed and still NULL. Then you pass NULL to your display function and obviously it does not display anything.

You can pass it by reference `node *create_ll(node*& start)` so that the create function would modify the actual `start` variable.

Also you don't need to put `struct` keyword before every `node` variable declaration in C++.